# Stack right floats properly when left div is not enough to fill the left column

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

Ive been playing around with floats, and i cant seem to figure out how to do this kind of layout.

```
A   B
    C
    D
```

when `div=A` does not fill the whole left column, the last right div (`div=D`) moves below `div=A`. 
visual here http://jsfiddle.net/pedenski/rGhY3/

when content of A is not enough to fill the entire left column, the last right `div` acts crazy.

Comment: [Can't you put B, C and D in a group container "E"](http://jsfiddle.net/AqqQE/)?

Comment: well, that works. didnt thought of that.. just made my day, thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this...what I did is made a two separate containers, float 1st to the left, 2nd to the right, and simply place all the three containers in the second container

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGhY3/1/)

Or if you want the height to be 100% you can do it like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGhY3/2/)

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    margin:auto;   
    background:#ccc;
      overflow: hidden;

}
#head {
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    background:purple;

}
#content {
    width: 190px;
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

#content2 {
float: right;
}
#side1 {
    width:190px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 5px 10px 0;

}#side2 {
    width:190px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 5px 10px 0;

}
#side3 {
    width:190px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 5px 10px 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="head">
    header
    </div>

        <div id="content">
            the quick brown fox
            the quick brown fox
            the quick brown fox
            the quick brown fox
            the quick brown fox
        </div>

       <div id="content2">
            <div id="side1">
            sidesidesideside
            sidesidesideside
            sidesidesideside
        </div>

    <div id="side2">
            sidesidesideside
            sidesidesideside
            sidesidesideside
        </div>

    <div id="side3">
            sidesidesideside
            sidesidesideside
            sidesidesideside
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess we had the same idea, I posted that as a comment a few minutes ago :)

Comment: thanks for this, same answer as above comment. i never thought putting all 3 right divs in a container, and float the container to the right. thats a clever trick i must say. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If div B, C, and D's heights are known, set div A's height to the sum. If their heights are not known, you can still set it dynamically wit javascript (without javascript, it'll look ugly but still be usable).